# combining replace and case statements

Tags: sql

Can you combine CASE and REPLACE statements?

I have this statement to show NULL as blank:

```
CASE 
    WHEN f.descriptionofwork IS NULL
    THEN 
         ''
    ELSE 
         f.descriptionofwork
END as 'Description'
```

But I also need to remove line breaks / returns in the data and would normally use this statement:

```
Replace(Replace(f.descriptionofwork,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') as 'Description'
```

How would I combine the two?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN f.descriptionofwork IS NULL THEN '' 
    ELSE Replace(Replace(f.descriptionofwork,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') 
END as 'Description'
```

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE()` is more concise than `CASE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Replace(Replace(f.descriptionofwork, CHAR(10), ''
                               ), CHAR(13), ''
                       ), '') as Description
```

You should not put column aliases in single quotes.  To avoid problems in your code only use single quotes for string and date constants.